# Export all braces in a String to an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, braces

example:

```
String = "(a(b[}7cv)))"
```

the array should look like this: `["(","(","[","}",")",")",")"]`

my try:

```
if(s.charAt(i) == "(" ){
    //add to array}
```

Comment: Please add more content in order to understand

Comment: Im a Java beginner. I tried searching the string with an for-loop but cant get it to work.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and help us

Comment: i want to ignore everything except the braces in a string and write them in an array

Comment: It is better to post your code that's not working

Comment: Assuming `String brackets = "()[]{}";` you can just do `"(a(b[}7cv)))".chars().mapToObj(ch -> String.valueOf((char) ch)).filter(brackets::contains).toArray(String[]::new)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply find them using regex and add them to a List

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String foo = "(a(b[}7cv)))";
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\W")
        .matcher(foo);
    while (m.find()) {
      allMatches.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(allMatches); 
  }
```

If it's only brackets you're after, you might want to take `"[(){}\\]\\[]"` as a regex for `Pattern.compile`

Answer (score 0):

How about getting non alphanumeric and add to the list

```
String s = "(a(b[}7cv)))";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    var list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (m.find()) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(m.start())));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

Output

```
[(, (, [, }, ), ), )]
```